# Removing Ubuntu from Windows 7 dual boot with multiple partitions

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have a Dell Studio 15 that dual boots Windows 7 and Ubuntu. All Windows and Ubuntu admin files (Documents, Videos etc..) are in a separate partition I use for a bridge.

If I can just remove the partition Ubuntu utilizes and all Admin files on the separate partition, will Windows automatically boot? Will I have to change bios settings because grub is no longer there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you will need to run startup repair with a windows 7 disk.

Comment: I immediately found this in a google search  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/

Answer (score 1):

If you run into a problem with using startup repair (I have when I was triple booting), you can also give "Super Grub" a try to repair the the startup and remove grub.

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/